# What is the name of bike fork spacer for shipping a bike frame?

Tags: frames, fork, transportation, carbon-fork

I am trying to pack my bike for an plane ride, and while packing I wanted to know what is the name of the spacer that needs to replace the wheel(s) between the fork dropouts to prevent frame compression/flexing/breakage without the wheel(s) installed.

It is the thing that replaces the quick release skewer or through axle.

Comment: I've seen this as _wheel placeholder_ but only as a nichè product for the rear dropout, including a roller to keep the chain tight for cleaning/adjusting. Why not just cut a small tube to length and use it with an actual thruaxle or QR skewer? However, I'm not sure if this will be a gamechange when your bike takes load from the side because forks are mainly built to take load longtitudinal forces. So, such spacer perhaps won't save your frame when it takes that much stress through the case/padding....

Comment: Regarding the photo (above the two answers), I agree one should also remove the derailleur to prevent damage from outside forces. The same ones that could compromise the front and rear dropouts might also cause mischief elsewhere. HVAC

Comment: Note: if you have a thru-axle bike, you don't need anything -- just use the axles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"bicycle dummy axle" or hub get good results in a search engine, including Park's DH-1.

[image] <sup>Because of course Park has a tool for that.</sup>

Depending on how tightly you need to pack the bike, there are other solutions too.   I would find/make/3Dprint a tube with flanged ends that allows the QR skewer to pass through and lock down.

The derailleur is vulnerable when packed, so its common to unbolt that, and wrap it in a plastic bag and zip-tie it to the frame.  This reduces the oiliness and you could then pack clothes or other items inside the frame between the stays to help fill the void and limit squashing.

If you have a good relationship with your LBS, then ask them for new-bike packing parts - they often have something left over from setting up a new bike out of a box.  You might get frame-foam and front/rear wheel tubes here.

Comment: Definitely ask at the LBS. They just throw away (or maybe recycle) all that stuff, so they shouldn't have any issue giving it to you.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't one unified name for them. Where I work in the PNW USA we pack bikes a lot and the approximate most common term for them is "fork block," but "fork spacer" or the more ambiguous "dropout spacer" are also used.